# How to show a value from model related to other model?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to show all lecture rooms ('sale') which are related with language English('jezyk'='EN')

I can not use such solution:

```
'sala': Sala.objects.filter(jezyk='3')
```

Because I defined in the options that user can define languages. In my project English has always "EN" key
[image]

I try to doing it in this way but it doesn't work

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from jezyk.models import Jezyk

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Tytul wiadomosci")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Zawartosc")
    published = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Data Publikacji")
    jezyk = models.ForeignKey('jezyk.Jezyk', null=True, related_name='jezyk_articles')
```

views.py

```
def articles(request):
    return render_to_response('articles.html',{'articles' : Article.objects.all(),'godzina': Godzina.objects.all(),'sala': Sala.objects.all() })
```

articles.html

```
{% if article.jezyk = sala.jezyk %}
    {% for sala in sala %}
        <div>{{ sala }}</div>
    {%endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use double underscore notation to get proper field of related model:

```
'sala': Sala.objects.filter(jezyk__jezyk='EN')
```

And mixing 2 languages in code (polish and english) is not looking great, try to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you :) Is it possible to do it that article.jezyk depens on sala.jezyk? I mean something like this: 'sala': Sala.objects.filter(jezyk=article.jezyk) If article is for english language exam it will be automatic showed a lecture room for english

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can read more on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/), more about related fields is on section Lookups that span relationships.

Comment: There is no answer for my question :(